# How to check if image is dropped in correct container?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm making an application where the user has to drag an object (eg. plastic bottle, can, crisp packet) into the correct bin (waste bin, recycle bin). I'm trying to make it so that once the user has dragged the object into the correct bin the next object pops up in the same image view and tells the user whether they've picked the correct bin or not.

In my mind I've done everything correctly, but the app keeps crashing as soon as I drag the object to one of the bins. What am I doing wrong?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView question, option1, option2, option3;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> drawableValues;
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    private int[] textureArrayWin = {
            R.drawable.image_0,
            R.drawable.image_1,
            R.drawable.image_2,
            R.drawable.image_3,
            R.drawable.image_4,
            R.drawable.image_5,
            R.drawable.image_6,
            R.drawable.image_7,
            R.drawable.image_8,
            R.drawable.image_9,
            R.drawable.image_10,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawableValues = new HashMap<>();
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_0, 1);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_1, 2);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_2, 3);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_3, 2);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_4, 3);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_5, 3);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_6, 1);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_7, 1);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_8, 1);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_9, 1);
        drawableValues.put(R.drawable.image_10, 1);

        question = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qImageView);
        question.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(textureArrayWin[currentIndex]));
        option1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gWBinImageView);
        option2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rBImageView);
        option3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.oWImageView);

        option1.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        option2.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        option3.setOnDragListener(dragListener);

        question.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    }

    View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, myShadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return true;
        }
    };

    View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int dragEvent = event.getAction();

            switch (dragEvent){

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    //view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;
                    ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

                    int answer = drawableValues.get(((ImageView) dropped).getDrawable());
                    int tagDropTarget = Integer.parseInt((String)dropTarget.getTag());

                    if (answer == tagDropTarget ){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.correctMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.incorrectMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1);
                    Drawable imageQuestion = getResources().getDrawable(textureArrayWin[currentIndex]);
                    question.setImageDrawable(imageQuestion);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

activity_main.xml (relevant parts)

```
        <ImageView
        android:tag="1"
        android:id="@+id/gWBinImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/general_waste" />

    <ImageView
        android:tag="2"
        android:id="@+id/rBImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/recycle_bin" />

    <ImageView
        android:tag="3"
        android:id="@+id/oWImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_waste" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Error log

```
2019-06-12 23:26:14.261 12092-12092/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12092
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$2.onDrag(MainActivity.java:93)
    at android.view.View.callDragEventHandler(View.java:26134)
    at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:26125)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1784)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1784)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1784)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1784)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1784)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1784)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1784)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6856)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1200(ViewRootImpl.java:146)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4719)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

Comment: Can you show you error log? Will be easier to trace like that.

Comment: I've edited the error log into the question.

Comment: now check the code on this line MainActivity.java:93, notice anything? if not simple paste that line on code here let me see.

Comment: The problem lies on this line: int answer = drawableValues.get(((ImageView) dropped).getDrawable());

Comment: This is wrong: final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
You're casting an object into a view.
event.getLocalState() got this from the documentation 
The object is intended to provide local information about the drag and drop operation. For
     * example, it can indicate whether the drag and drop operation is a copy or a move.